# Error importing middleware cms.middleware.page: "No module named middleware.page"

Tags: python

Im unable to import a module even though my path appears correct.

```
>>> import cms.middleware.page
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named middleware.page
```

Heres shows my path is ok

```
>>> for x in sys.path:
...     if x == "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages":
...         print x
...
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Heres the module

```
[root@monty codecrab]# ls -l /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/middleware/page.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1304 Apr 17 19:49 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/middleware/page.py
```

Here are the files

```
[root@monty cms]# pwd
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms
[root@monty cms]# ls -l __init__.py middleware/__init__.py middleware/page.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   47 Apr 17 19:49 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 17 19:49 middleware/__init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1304 Apr 17 19:49 middleware/page.py
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: What does 'import cms; print cms.__path__' output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to an incorrect installation of your package.

To be able to do `import cms.middleware.page`, the `cms` directory must be on your Python path, with both `cms` and `middleware` directories containing an `__init__.py` file so that they are treated as a Python package.

The following files/directories must exist:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/middleware
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/middleware/__init__.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/middleware/page.py
```

Comment: thanks, but ive just checked and all the files are there. question updated

Comment: @felix001 For reference, if all of the files were in place, what was causing the problem with the failed import?

Comment: I had created a app called cms as well by confusion, which I think may of been polluting the namespace.